# Passing a datetime through request.form in ASP

Tags: html, asp-classic

I'm trying to pass values from 2 drop down menus from a submit button using request.form.

The values i'm trying to pass are datetimes that come from SQL show below:

```
           <select name="startshift" id="startshift"> 
       <%     
    While Not oRSShifts.EOF
    response.Write("<option value=" & ORSShifts("Shift_Start_Time") & "> " & ORSShifts("Shift_Start_Time") & " </option>")    
    oRSShifts.MoveNext 
    WEND
    %>
    </select>
    TO:
    <select name="endshift" id="endshift"> 
      <%   
    oRSShifts.MoveFirst  
    While Not oRSShifts.EOF
    response.Write("<option value=" & ORSShifts("Shift_End_Time") & "> " & ORSShifts("Shift_End_Time") & " </option>")    
    oRSShifts.MoveNext 
    WEND
    %>
    </select>
```

When the submit button is pressed i use the ASP below to collect the values:

```
strstartshift = Request.Form("startshift")
strendshift = Request.Form("endshift")
```

The problem I'm having is, the correct value in the drop down list is for example: `01/01/2014 07:00:00` however the value that is collected by `request.form` is `01/01/2014` leaving out the time.

Any help appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Could be a number of things.  First, try enclosing the date/time value in quotes, i.e., `<option value='" & ORSShifts("Shift_End_Time") & '">`.

Comment: Joe, once again, thanks. That worked. Want to post this as the answer and ill accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The date/time value has a space, so it needs to be included in quotes in order to be passed correctly as a form value.  Try:

```
response.Write("<option value='" & ORSShifts("Shift_End_Time") & '">")
```